# Implementation of AnyMap and runtime overhead of `struct Port(u32);`

Tags: metaprogramming, rust

I was reading "24 days of Rust" and [the example of `AnyMap` usage](http://siciarz.net/24-days-of-rust-anymap/) just blew my mind. Consider the following code:

```
#[deriving(Show)]
struct Port(u32);

#[deriving(Show)]
struct ConnectionLimit(u32);
```

It says:

> Here the `Port` and `ConnectionLimit` types are abstractions over the
>   underlying integer (**with no overhead at runtime**!).

Very well, I can understand how this could be achieved. All types are checked during compilation and in runtime we have only u32's. But in this case how is it possible to create a map from some `TypeId` to `Box<Any>`? And how Any could be casted to any subtype, like u32?

The [source code on `AnyMap`](https://github.com/chris-morgan/anymap/) is quite complicated and a lot of metaprogramming is involved. How does it work? Maybe there is just a mistake in "24 days of Rust" and `Port` and `ConnectionLimit` actually have runtime overhead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is pretty common in C, C++ and other system languages to have different types with the same in-memory representation.

In memory:

- a `u32` is 4 contiguous bytes of memory
- a `Port` is 4 contiguous bytes of memory
- a `ConnectionLimit` is 4 contiguous bytes of memory

Notably, compared to many other languages, there is no "virtual table" or other extraneous information stored in memory for each instance of those types.

As for `AnyMap`, at the point where you store your object in the map, the compiler knows the type of the object, and therefore can provide the correct `TypeId`. This then has to be carried along preciously with the object data, because if it is ever lost it cannot be recovered.

Comment: So, TypeId is just a constant generated during the compilation and used inside generic get/set functions. And according to the source code, types are casted to/from Any in unsafe block, which actually is quite safe, because we know exactly which type is used in every generic function. Right?

Comment: @afiskon: You can use Any without `unsafe`, from what I know, however it is itself implement with `unsafe` behind the scenes because it manipulates raw memory.

Comment: Just to be clear, the functionality of anymap can be implemented in completely safe code; it can just be made somewhat more efficient by the use of unsafe code there which is indeed infallible, for the TypeId is stored as the key also and is by generic constraints and so forth known statically.